# Using RequireJS with a Rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, requirejs

**Question**

If you've used RequireJS with a Rails 3 (esp 3.1) app, how is that working for you? Any configuration tricks or other gotchas that I need to watch out for?

**Background**

I'm contemplating using RequireJS over the Sprockets-based Asset Pipeline in Rails 3.1, specifically for JavaScript code.  I have two motivators for this choice:

- I want to leverage RequireJS' module management for my JS client-side code.
- I'd like a precompilation system that can follow my JS library code into other contexts. To my surprise, the Asset Pipeline precompiler is a baked-in part of Rails, not a part of Sprockets itself.

All feedback appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you tell more about why you would want RequireJS' module management over Sprockets' one? I'm thinking about doing the same thing for our Rails app — replacing Sprockets with RequireJS.

Comment: @kangax, Sprockets doesn't really provide module management.  It just conglomerates a bunch of JavaScript into a built file via Sprockets' directives.  As it happens, I've published the [requirejs-rails](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/) gem to integrate RequireJS into Rails, leveraging Sprockets for CoffeeScript conversions. Nearing 0.5.0 release with precompliation support.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For posterity, here's where I've come to on this question:

- RequireJS provides an implementation of the [Asynchronous Module Definition](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition) API. RequireJS' [Why AMD? page](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) lays out the case as to why you'd want to use this.
- Sprockets and the Rails 3 Asset Pipeline allow for simple structuring of JavaScript/CoffeeScript code, but don't provide any true module support.  For example, there's no namespace control whatsoever in Sprockets.
- jQuery (as of 1.7), Underscore, Dojo and numerous other major libraries have implemented AMD support.  Several other major JS libraries seem to have AMD support on the near-term horizion (e.g. Backbone.js).

It's certainly possible to create a Rails app that integrates RequireJS.  To simplify that process, I've created the [requirejs-rails gem on github](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/), with straightforward configuration and Asset Pipeline-aware precompilation for AMD-based code via [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js).  The current release is available via:

`gem install requirejs-rails`

Comment: Also for posterity, Underscore no longer supports AMD. However, Lodash, a drop-in replacement for Underscore, does. http://lodash.com

Comment: Thanks for this gem. Is there code Rails app I can see that shows how it's all set up, preferably with Backbone. I've read the docs, but I'm new to require.js and not that experienced/skilled with javascript, so I get along much better with a working example.

Comment: Here is an example Rails 4 application which integrates requirejs-rails: https://github.com/pboling/require-rails-example

Comment: @leppert You can always use shim configuration and export "_".