# Rails 3.2 + Require.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, requirejs

I've been reading a lot of info on Require.js. AMD seems very interesting and I got it to work in a standalone backbone.js app. However, Sprocket in Rails seems to conflict with it. Do you recommend projects to go with standard Rails asset pipeline without Require.js?

I saw this article but it's for Rails 3.1, so not sure if it's still applicable: [Using RequireJS with a Rails 3.1 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921445/using-requirejs-with-a-rails-3-1-app)

Also, Underscore no longer seems to be supporting AMD. I don't want to use yet another package to work with Backbone.

Comment: To answer the last part of your question, requirejs now supports a `shim` config option that will allow usage of non-AMD libraries (like Underscore) - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: There are gems for this:

gem 'requirejs-rails'

Answer (score 0):

I did this awhile ago I used the "use" requireJS plugin to load incompatible libs like underscore.js

https://github.com/tbranyen/use.js

and I think I only included require.js into the sprockets assets, and used it like in any other application.